# how to set an array with if statments

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a program that is meant to output a message based on their form input on the previous page which I have grabbed with `$_GET` on the next page with php.

If believe it is something to do with setting the array with an if else statement.

Here is my php and JavaScript code :

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    $theirname = $_GET['theirname'];
    $yourname = $_GET['yourname'];
    $slct2 = $_GET['slct2'];
    $slct1 = $_GET['slct1'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var theirName = "<?php echo $theirname; ?>";
    var yourName = "<?php echo $yourname; ?>";
    var cardType = "<?php echo $slct1; ?>";
    var personType = "<?php echo $slct2; ?>";

    var myArray=[

"i need", 
"to make the contents of ",  
"this array",  
"conditional",  
"to the variable",  
"cardType",  
"and the variable",  
"personType", 


];

 //shuffle array:
myArray.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random());});

//print to screen
function printGreet()
{
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= [myArray.pop()];
}
</script>
```

And html:

```
    <button onclick="printGreet()" class="large-btn" id="generate-Btn" rows="20">Generate</button>
</div>
<div id="yourMes">
    <p>Your message:</p>
</div>
<textarea name="text1" class="large-fld" id="demo"> </textarea>
```

Demo of my site for more elaboration, here: http://ngrdev.com/jack/greatgreets2/index.php

Comment: var_dump($_GET['yourname']) ?

Comment: If you redefine the myArray in a funtion it will be destroyed when that function ends. Remove the var

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work. It is simply not printing anything at all

Comment: yeah I don' think you read what he said fully, what you should have done was to remove the var declaration whilest keeping the rest of the line, what you did was remove the entire line

Comment: further more what have you tried and what results have you been getting?

Comment: @Touchpad the edit i have made is working. now i would like to make the contents of myArray conditional. results i have gotten with the edited code is a successful print.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give what kind of value $_GET['slct2'] contain? As you are doing json_encode in php to $slct2 variable then you need to do json decode for cardType in javascript.

Use json_encode in php, if your data is a array format or string with characters.

For json decode check http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp.

Comment: check out http://ngrdev.com/jack/greatgreets2/index.php
Hopefully that helps.

I believe it is a string but this is only my second actual project

i dont think i need the jso_encode but i was trying alot of things to get it to work.

Comment: in essence all i really need to know how to do is make the var conditional - ill change the question to make it more easily understandable.